# How to decompose URL into model and parameters in Django

Tags: python, django

Basically, I want the reverse version of `get_absolute_url` method in Django model.

For example, if we have a model:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    ...

    get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('myview', args=(myparam=self.myfield,))
```

then in some view we should be able to do something like this:

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/path/to/myview/123'
model, params = decompose(url)
# now model="MyModel", params=('123',)
```

**EDIT:**

If it's too difficult to achieve, how about re-reversing views only?

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/path/to/myview/123'
view, params = decompose(url)
# now view="MyView", params=('123',)
```

Comment: I don;t think there is an easy way to do this, you may just have to write your own

Comment: @tr33hours comment should be promoted to an answer, and it should be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.core import urlresolvers

match = urlresolvers.resolve(urlsplit(url).path)
view = match.func
params = match.args
```

Solution from [django-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/3sDvkvq4xqM).

Comment: `math.args`? Should that be `match.args`?